# Why flutter_bloc throwing bad state exception when using FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen()

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-bloc

I'm trying to use A Bloc where I am also using the FirebaseAuth plugin to monitor all changes happening in the authentication flow through the **FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges** stream. I am using flutter_bloc version ^7.3.0 and firebase_auth version ^3.1.1. The bloc code is the following:

```
class AuthBloc extends Bloc<AuthEvent, AuthState> {
  late StreamSubscription<User?> authStreamSub;

  AuthBloc() : super(FetchingCredentialsState()) {
    authStreamSub = FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((event) {
      print('listening to authStateChanges. I guess these lines of code cause the error');
    });

    on<LoginAuthEvent>((event, emit) {
      print(
          'Processing a LoginAuthEvent with email ${event.email} and password 
      ${event.password}');
      emit.call(LoginUserState());
    });

    on<AuthLoadedEvent>((event, emit) {
      print('new AuthLoadedEvent');
      var authLoadedState = AuthLoadedState(
          userCredentials: event.userCredentials,
          isAuthenticated: event.isAuthenticated);
      emit.call(authLoadedState);
    });
  }

  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    //authStreamSub.cancel();
    return super.close();
  }
}
```

It seems like this code **authStreamSub = FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((event) {
print('listening to authStateChanges');
});** inside the AuthBloc constructor is what is causing the error, due when I remove that line the error is gone. I put the stack trace below:

```
══════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following StateError was thrown building InheritedProvider<AuthBloc>:
Bad state: Tried to read a provider that threw during the creation of its value.
The exception occurred during the creation of type AuthBloc.

The relevant error-causing widget was
InheritedProvider<AuthBloc>
C:\…\src\bloc_provider.dart:126
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      _CreateInheritedProviderState.value
package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:701
#1      _CreateInheritedProviderState.debugFillProperties
package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:793
#2      _InheritedProviderScopeElement.debugFillProperties
package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:624
#3      DiagnosticableNode.builder.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/foundation/diagnostics.dart:2945
#4      DiagnosticableNode.builder
package:flutter/…/foundation/diagnostics.dart:2948

═══════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4269 pos 14: 
'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was
BlocProvider<AuthBloc>
lib\main.dart:50

═══════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4269 pos 14: 
'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was
_NestedHook
C:\…\lib\nested.dart:103
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

═══════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4269 pos 14: 
'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was
MultiBlocProvider
lib\main.dart:48
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

═══════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4269 pos 14: 
'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was
MultiBlocProvider
lib\main.dart:48
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4269 pos 14: 
'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was
FutureBuilder<FirebaseApp>
lib\main.dart:31
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4269 pos 14: 
'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was
MyApp
lib\main.dart:14
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4269 pos 14: 
'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

More lines are below these lines I post here, but I think (and hope) is enough with the lines I included.
Any kind of help will be appreciated. :)

P.D.: I have tried to pass the FirebaseAuth instance in the AuthBloc Constructor, but still the same error. I don't know why if I try to access to the listen method, the error is throw.

Comment: It was my bad. I was creating the Bloc with the lazy property to false in the MultiBlocProvider.providers Array, that causes a call to the FirebaseAuth.instance when Firebase.initializeApp was not called yet.
Now I'm facing a new error, when I push the back button and the app go to background, then I return to my app from the recent apps screen, and the AuthBloc is recreated again, causing the same error than before, because no FirebaseApp initialization has happened.